# The height of the images on each side of the text and that adjusts according to the size of the text

Tags: html, css, position

I want the height of the images between brackets to match depending on the height of the text in the center. How can I do that with css?

The orange color is the top/bottom margin of the text.

with a small text it should look like this:
[image]

with a big text it should look like this:
[image]

The images must adapt to all sizes and especially that they can be large to have a good resolution.

If possible without Javascript...

Here is what I tried: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ttpdek?file=style.css)

In this DEMO, either the height of the image doesn't change, as in the first example. Either the width of the text doesn't fit correctly, as in the second example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i did this before and not able to find it :) ... but will do it !

Comment: found it ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744166/how-to-fit-image-height-to-juxtaposed-text-height/47744364#47744364 not the exact situation but very similar, so you can get some idea